# Unable to instantiate a python class - AttributeError: class object has no attribute 'language'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-class

I replicated a `TextNormalizer` class from this [book](https://www.amazon.com.au/Applied-Analysis-Python-Benjamin-Bengfort/dp/1491963042/ref=asc_df_1491963042/?tag=googleshopdsk-22&linkCode=df0&hvadid=341743255824&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=9701722404310316585&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9071722&hvtargid=pla-446885923402&psc=1) like this

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
class TextNormalizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, language='english'):
        self.stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words(language))
        self.lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    def remove_concat(self, narrative):
        chars_to_remove = ['-', '_', '+']
        reg_ex = '[' + re.escape (''. join (chars_to_remove)) + ']'
        return re.sub(reg_ex, ' ', narrative) 
    
    def process_narrative(self, narrative):
        cleaned_narrative = self.remove_concat(narrative)
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(cleaned_narrative)
        return [token.lower() for token in tokens if token.lower() not in self.stopwords]
```

I wanted to learn the code step by step by testing it like this

```
tn = TextNormalizer()
tn
```

The following error occurred

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs)
    462     def _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs):
    463         """Mime bundle used by jupyter kernels to display estimator"""
--> 464         output = {"text/plain": repr(self)}
    465         if get_config()["display"] == 'diagram':
    466             output["text/html"] = estimator_html_repr(self)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    258             n_max_elements_to_show=N_MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_SHOW)
    259 
--> 260         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    261 
    262         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    151     def pformat(self, object):
    152         sio = _StringIO()
--> 153         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    154         return sio.getvalue()
    155 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    168             self._readable = False
    169             return
--> 170         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    171         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    172         if len(rep) > max_width:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    402 
    403     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
--> 404         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
    405                                                 self._depth, level)
    406         if not readable:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    178 
    179     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
--> 180         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
    181                           changed_only=self._changed_only)
    182 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    423         recursive = False
    424         if changed_only:
--> 425             params = _changed_params(object)
    426         else:
    427             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
     89     estimator with non-default values."""
     90 
---> 91     params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     92     init_func = getattr(estimator.__init__, 'deprecated_original',
     93                         estimator.__init__)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in get_params(self, deep)
    193         out = dict()
    194         for key in self._get_param_names():
--> 195             value = getattr(self, key)
    196             if deep and hasattr(value, 'get_params'):
    197                 deep_items = value.get_params().items()

AttributeError: 'TextNormalizer' object has no attribute 'language'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    392                         if cls is not object \
    393                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 394                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    395 
    396             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    698     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    699     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 700     output = repr(obj)
    701     lines = output.splitlines()
    702     with p.group():

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    258             n_max_elements_to_show=N_MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_SHOW)
    259 
--> 260         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    261 
    262         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    151     def pformat(self, object):
    152         sio = _StringIO()
--> 153         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    154         return sio.getvalue()
    155 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    168             self._readable = False
    169             return
--> 170         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    171         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    172         if len(rep) > max_width:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    402 
    403     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
--> 404         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
    405                                                 self._depth, level)
    406         if not readable:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    178 
    179     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
--> 180         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
    181                           changed_only=self._changed_only)
    182 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    423         recursive = False
    424         if changed_only:
--> 425             params = _changed_params(object)
    426         else:
    427             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
     89     estimator with non-default values."""
     90 
---> 91     params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     92     init_func = getattr(estimator.__init__, 'deprecated_original',
     93                         estimator.__init__)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in get_params(self, deep)
    193         out = dict()
    194         for key in self._get_param_names():
--> 195             value = getattr(self, key)
    196             if deep and hasattr(value, 'get_params'):
    197                 deep_items = value.get_params().items()

AttributeError: 'TextNormalizer' object has no attribute 'language'
```

Although the class `TextNormalizer` would throw the above error if I tried to instantiate it, but it worked if applied to text like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['My order_number is A-08', 'It cost me +$80.00']})
tn = TextNormalizer()
df['description'].apply(tn.process_narrative)
```

Which produced this output

```
0    [order, number, 08]
1       [cost, $, 80.00]
Name: description, dtype: object
```

Can someone please explain what is happening? I meant it worked although it seemed wrong. What's the reason for this "*phenomenon*"?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with the code provided. I get: `NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined`. Can you edit your post to include where `nltk` is defined?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but try adding `self.language = language` to the `__init__` function.

Comment: @JohnGordon, having `self.language = languageI` did eliminate the error message. Howerver, I replicated the above code from this book (https://www.amazon.com.au/Applied-Analysis-Python-Benjamin-Bengfort/dp/1491963042/ref=asc_df_1491963042/?tag=googleshopdsk-22&linkCode=df0&hvadid=341743255824&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=9701722404310316585&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9071722&hvtargid=pla-446885923402&psc=1). The author's code would work without `self.language = language`. What is going on?

Comment: It is likely that the code in the library has changed since the publication of the book, or that the book was incorrect at time of publication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to also download the stopwords, but setting `self.language = language` in the code and then using either `language` or `self.language` to retrieve the correct list resolves the error.

Removing the `language` parameter and all lines using it also runs without issue, so it just doesn't like the parameter being specified, but not used.

```py
import nltk
import pandas as pd
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
class TextNormalizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, language='english'):
        self.language = language
        self.stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words(self.language))
        self.lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

test = TextNormalizer()
test
```

---

**Addendum**

The reason

```py
tn
```

from the OP returns an error is because `language` isn't being set when the `TextNormalizer` object is instantiated, and because that value is used in the object's representation of itself.

When the single line:

```py
tn
```

is run, this does not instantiate the object `tn`, which must already exist. It evaluates and returns the value of `__repr__` (which is defined somewhere in `nltk`). No error arises from creation of the `class` itself because the `__repr__` method is not evaluated until you run `tn` on its own, or `repr(tn)`.

```py
df['description'].apply(tn.process_narrative)
```

does not throw an error because `tn` already exists, and its `__repr__` method is not being used.

You can fix this by assigning `self.language` as discussed above, or doing this after the item is created:

```py
tn = TextNormalizer()
tn.language = 'english'
tn
```

Comment: The question has changed. Can you please edit your answer to address the issue? Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example (added in the original post) where you do this: "The code would work if applied to text"? I don't know this specific package well enough to know what you mean.

Comment: I edited the OP with a working example as per your suggestion.

Comment: See the **Addendum** section in my answer. I think that will explain what's going on.

Comment: As I'm not a programmer so I wasn't quite following your explanation. I would agree with  it if not for the fact that the attribute `language` is already a defined default value in this line `def __init__(self, language='english')`, thus it's already set? Also `tn` instantiated `TextNormalizer` so what did you mean by `tn` *does not instantiate the object* `tn`? Also, why does `tn` have to *evaluates and returns the value of `__repr__`*? Thanks

Comment: Instantiation is happening when you create the object in `tn = TextNormalizer()`. That is the only time you are instantiating anything. If you just run `tn` after that, python evaluates `__repr__` for `tn` because that's what python does if you run code that just consists of a variable name. The `language` parameter has a default value when a new `TextNormalize` object is created, but *unless that value is then assigned to `self.language`*, the resulting `TextNormalizer` object won't have that attribute assigned. Without an assignment, the `'english'` value might as well not be there.